# Does data exchange between each instance of Durable functions use a task hub?

Tags: azure, networking, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to program using Durable functions.

The structure of the program is Client functions->Orchestration functions->Activity functions->... . The structure of the program is as follows.

In this case, how is the data transfer in each function?
Is the value of the return statement stored in the task hub and the next function uses it to proceed?
Or is the data sent to each function and instance via network communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication between orchestration functions and activity functions take place using messages as stated in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-task-hubs?tabs=csharp):

> While a function app is running, the progress of orchestration, activity, and entity functions is continually stored in the task hub.
>
> [..]
>
> Internally, each storage provider may use a different organization to represent instance states and messages. For example, messages are stored in Azure Storage Queues by the Azure Storage provider, but in relational tables by the MSSQL provider.

For a detailed reference, see [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-task-hubs?tabs=csharp#execution-example)